# Joomla выбор правильного изображения при расшаривании в Facebook

Tags: joomla, facebook, share

Удалось сформировать правильный META tag, по рекомендации от Facebook:

```
$article = JTable::getInstance("content");
$article->load(JRequest::getInt("id")); // Get Article ID
$article_images = $article->get("images"); // Get image parameters
$pictures = json_decode($article_images); // Split the parameters apart
```

вывести:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://aboutphuket.ru/<?php echo $pictures->{'image_intro'}; ?>" />
```

Если перейти по урл http://goo.gl/OTj7Pw, и посмотреть этот тег, то выводится он правильно, но почему Facebook при расшаривании страницы, все равно не видит этой самой картинки.

**Обновление**

Это страничка с моего сайта, попробуйте поделиться ей на facebook, он либо не найдет картинку вообще, либо будет подставлять неправильные. Я хочу чтобы при шаре фиксированно подставлялась первая картинка. Это делается кодом который я указал выше. Но УРЛ картинки генерируется я не могу указывать его для каждой страницы вручную. Мне нужно как-то подставить в META URL первой картинки [поста](http://www.aboutphuket.ru/Glavnaya/Putevoditel-po-stranam-yugo-vostochnoiy-%D0%90zii/Putevoditel-po-Taiylandu/Taiyskiiy-yazik/S-chego-nachat-izuchenie-taiyskogo-yazika.html).

**Обновление 2**

Comment: Необходимо больше информации. Может укажите ссылку, которую вы используете?

Comment: Уау... я в шоке. Даже не знаю с чего начать.  Лучше всего начать вам с [учебника](http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml) по Html простейшего. Если кратко, то, например, все элементы `<meta>` должны находится в области `<head>`. Тоже самое касается стилей для IE которые вы поставили в самые первые строки.

Comment: Я понимаю, вы по ходу не поняли о чем я . Я понимаю, что мета выводится в head , там она у меня вся и есть, вот в этой мете делается рекомендация от FB , там ставится ссылка на картинку, как мне сказать джумле с помощью PHP чтобы она вывела туда путь до первого изображения? Ответ если честно мало того что не полезный так еще и не в тему вообще.

Comment: @Alex, перенесите, пожалуйста, ваши уточнения в сам вопрос, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Comment: @Alex `<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>    <html class="no-js ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]><!--> <html> <!--<![endif]-->
<div id="preloader">
 <div id="status">&nbsp;</div> 
</div>
<head>
  `

Comment: @Alex У вас `<div>` до `<head>`. Хотя мне все равно, вы специалист.

Comment: Да какая разница когда грузится HEAD если в нем нет нужной META?

Comment: Вместо того чтобы в проблеме разобраться занимаетесь модераторством правками какими то переносами. Сами же потом столкнетесь, будете искать. Я почти разобрался.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ тут ссылку введите. Оно кэш фейсбука обновит

Comment: Спасибо, попробовал, но не помогло, все равно не ту картинку вставляет

Comment: http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/641244/efe2643e617b5b7436c2615cb6d455f6

Comment: Все заработало ,всем спасибо. В Debug tools видимо обновилось чуть позже и все стало норм. Код и meta работают.